# Code for uicollection view in ios6 - Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios6

Can anybody share the code relating to uicollection view in iOS6. I want to use it having the link to SQLlite database and images built over it.

Comment: [here](http://rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2013/03/uicollection-view-in-ios-6-tutorial.html) is the easy tutorial for collection view

Answer (score 2):

I have found a very simple tutorial for the same.

It is very easy and i've made my first demo using this only. I hope this will help you too

http://www.adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial.php